# advertisement notice in native video player

Tags: ios, video, overlay, ads

If using Brightcove HTML video player on a web page, iOS will open the related video (and any pre-roll ad's) in the native video player when play is pressed. Is there any way to show a message such as "Advertisement playing" within the native video player?

I have read that through the ad network, you can set some metadata which would notify the native player and result in a message being displayed. This information may be wrong and I have not found any information on how to do this.

Thanks in advance for any help.